# how to install application dependency of lib in centos 6?

Tags: google-chrome, pycharm, centos6

I am having a trouble installation applications dependency of 'lib'. Below are the two applications I want to install

- google-chrome-stable
- pycharm

Here the things I have setup recently did

- Fresh installation of centos6
- yum update (all updates are installed)
- yum install python3
- I tried to install pycharm it gives error of libjli.so & so on..

```
# ./pycharm.sh
/opt/pycharm-community-2020.2.2/jbr/bin/java: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /opt/pycharm-community-2020.2.2/jbr/bin/../lib/jli/libjli.so)
```

- When i try to install google-chrome-stable it throws error list of dependency missing

```
yum install google-chrome-stable
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in
 * centosplus: mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in
 * contrib: mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in
 * epel: download.nus.edu.sg
 * epel-testing: download.nus.edu.sg
 * extras: mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in
 * updates: mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package google-chrome-stable.x86_64 0:85.0.4183.121-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.16)(64bit) for package: google-chrome-stable-85.0.4183.121-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: liberation-fonts for package: google-chrome-stable-85.0.4183.121-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libappindicator3.so.1()(64bit) for package: google-chrome-stable-85.0.4183.121-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libvulkan.so.1()(64bit) for package: google-chrome-stable-85.0.4183.121-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgdk-3.so.0()(64bit) for package: google-chrome-stable-85.0.4183.121-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libatspi.so.0()(64bit) for package: google-chrome-stable-85.0.4183.121-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0()(64bit) for package: google-chrome-stable-85.0.4183.121-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgtk-3.so.0()(64bit) for package: google-chrome-stable-85.0.4183.121-1.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-85.0.4183.121-1.x86_64 (google-chrome)
           Requires: libgtk-3.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-85.0.4183.121-1.x86_64 (google-chrome)
           Requires: libvulkan.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-85.0.4183.121-1.x86_64 (google-chrome)
           Requires: libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-85.0.4183.121-1.x86_64 (google-chrome)
           Requires: libatspi.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-85.0.4183.121-1.x86_64 (google-chrome)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.16)(64bit)
Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-85.0.4183.121-1.x86_64 (google-chrome)
           Requires: libgdk-3.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-85.0.4183.121-1.x86_64 (google-chrome)
           Requires: liberation-fonts
Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-85.0.4183.121-1.x86_64 (google-chrome)
           Requires: libappindicator3.so.1()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

NOTE : I found few articles across the web which have method of installing 'glibc' & so but none of them is working.

**I have couple of questions :**

- How should I solve pycharm dependency to make it work ?
- How should I solve google-chrome-dependecy to make it work?
- What is the right approach to deal with dependency condition and installing lib with any kind of application installation.